# in mongodb , what is node driver topology classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[MONGODB NODE.JS DRIVER v3.3](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/reference/unified-topology/) mentioned that node driver has `seven topology classes`

can you explain what it is ?

Answer (score 1):

It's how a client searches for a server in the network graph to create and manage a connection.

1. Single node
2. [Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/)
3. [Shard cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/)
4. [Zone](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/zone-sharding/)
5. [Shard Key](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/)
6. [Config server](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/)
7. [Balancer](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/)